# Connecting from .NET to MQ-Series

Tags: ibm-mq

There are similar questions to this one, but not quite the same...

I have a C# program that is using amqmdnet.dll (from 9.0.1.0 MQC Redist)
The code to connect is:

```
Hashtable mqProperties = new Hashtable();   
mqProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName); 
mqProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostname); 
mqProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port); 
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(strQueueManagerName, mqProperties);
```

It works fine and writes to the queue. I assume it picks up my current login id from Windows.

When I run the same code on IIS, it connects but fails with an auth error 2035 when trying to write to the Queue.I assume this is because IIS is running as a different user-id.

I tried adding:

```
mqProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myuserid");
mqProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");
```

and it did not work. Trying "mydomain\myuserid" did not work either. Some other posts mentioned that MQ needs the Windows SID. I tried using that string, but that did not work either.

At this point, I am playing with this, so I'd prefer not to ask the admins to set up a new userid on the MQ server side. With this in mind, is there any way I can login when running under the IIS user, but pass in my userid/password or some other credential to make this work?

Comment: It is V9 or V10 (I believe it might have been upgraded just in the last week)

Comment: I wanted to make sure my answer is correct, did the suggested changes work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If the queue manager is v8.0 or later and is configured to use CONNAUTH and has ADOPTCTX(YES) set you can present an id and password.  If it does not have this set then the value presented in the UserId and Password property of a .NET client will be ignored.

A IBM developerWorks MQdev blog post "[MQCSP Password Protection in MQ V8](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/websphere_mqcsp_password_protection_in_mq_v8?lang=en) has details on how to do this in various languages."

For .NET you should be able to use what you have with the addition of the `MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY` set to `true`:

```
mqProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myuserid");
mqProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");
mqProperties.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);
```

The queue manager will then authenticate this ID.  If the queue manager is set with ADOPTCTX(YES) then it will always use the authenticated ID for OAM checks.  If it is set to ADOPTCTX(NO) it will still use the ID the process is running under to perform OAM checks.  It is highly recommended that this be set to ADOPTCTX(YES).

**Update 2017/02/20**:

Related to the comment "I can see that it might be turned off by admins so that MQ relies on the larger organizational SSO infrastructure.".  Without setting up CONNAUTH and ADOPTCTX(YES) you can assert **any** id you want to over the channel.  If a CHLAUTH rule is not in place to block administrative users then you can obtain full MQ administrative authority without any form of authentication.

Comment: This looks like what I was doing (I added the MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, but with the same result). 
I will need to ask about CONNAUTH and ADOPTCTX(YES). I think you're saying a logged in Windows user would be able to connect to MQ without those, but I need those to be set if I want to send the Userid/Password explicitly. I can see that it might be turned off by admins so that MQ relies on the larger organizational SSO infrastructure.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, not yet. Though it is something we are going to need, it has been deferred for now.

Comment: I have nearly the same issue, but instead I'm sending the userID and pw which is a local user on the server. But without sucess..

Comment: What does your AMQERR01.LOG show when your connection fails?

Comment: The server keeps doing the authentication on the windows user I start the client application with... Even if I pass the UserId and Password properties

Comment: What is your ADOPTCTX value set to on the CONNAUTH AUTHINFO object?  If you have CONNAUTH set to OPTIONAL, REQADM, or REQUIRED then authentication would happen based on the UserId and Password sent.  If ADOPTCTX(NO) then authorization is based on the user that starts the process, if ADOPTCTX(YES) then authorization is based on the UserId sent with the Password.

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I found it out. Apparently there is also a property which could be set to 'y' in the qm.ini file called chlauthEarlyAdopt

Comment: chlauthEarlyAdopt is a different property.  It is related to if CHLAUTH USERMAP rules will work against the MQCSP user sent, by default with out chlauthEarlyAdopt they work against the user the application is started with.

Comment: @DariusX. I updated my answer to reflect that the MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY is required, did you ever resolve your issue?

Comment: @DariusX. I recently noticed in the [IBM MQ v9 Knowledge Center page "User IDs"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q010300_.htm) that it shows an example of passing an id to a windows queue manager of `id@domain`, I noticed in your question you stated you tried `myuserid` and `mydomain\myuserid`, maybe this could be causing the issue you faced.

Comment: @JoshMc: Thank you so much for following up. We're still in a hold pattern on this, but I'll send that link to the developer.

Comment: As an FYI, our project is planning to forward with this again in Q2 2018, so I will get a chance to provide an update.